# OGRE COLLADA Library source

Tags: collada, ogre

I am trying to use OGRE Collada source code. Unfortunately I got only executables from source forge.net.

Does anybody have the source code for OGRE COLLADA?

This is the link I opened. 
http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=OgreCollada

and I downloaded a fantastic viewer app
https://sourceforge.net/projects/ogrecollada/?source=directory

I am looking for the source code for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I built it sometime in the past - it seems to be [here](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/ogrecollada/svn/trunk/)